# Iterating over keys instead of objects in AngularJS 2

Tags: angular

I have a use case in AngularJS 2 where I have an object with an attribute that is an array of keys, like this:

```js
export class Region {
    m49: string;
    parent: string;
    regions: string[];
    countries: string[];
    name: string; 
}
```

I have a service that takes a key, and returns the corresponding object:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PlaceService {
    getRegion(m49: string) {
        ...
    }
    getCountry(iso: string) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a component that displays the information about a region, and then lists the sub-regions and countries. This displays the region and country keys properly.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'places',
    template: `
<div>
  <h2>{{region.name}}</h2>
  <div>
    <h3>Regions</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let m49 of region.regions">{{m49}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Countries</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let iso of region.countries">{{iso}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
`,
    providers: [ PlaceService ]
})
```

But what I'd really like to do is to get the region and country objects in the loops, and display their properties. How do I invoke a method of the component class to call the service, and retrieve an object, from the `<li>` elements? Secondarily, how can I use `*ngIf` on the two child `div` elements to only include them if the respective lists are non-empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to call the component method do this

```
{{ componentMethod() }}
```

and to include div if list is not empty do this

```
<div *ngIf="list.length > 0"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If componentMethod() returns an object (say, of the Region type above), how would I assign the return value to a local variable so that I can use it within the HTML element?

Comment: you can return the specific property or you can use json pipe like this to display whole object <div>{{componentMethodObject | json}}</div>

Comment: That's closer, but how would I, for example, display the m49 and name attribute of a region object in the list? I know the following isn't correct, but something like: <..."with r = getRegion()">{{r.m49}}: {{r.name}}

Comment: for this you have to do like this {{getRegion().m49}} : {{getRegion().name}}

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like, for this particular use case, the best way is to make another sub-component with just the <li> element.

Comment: yes better to make some other child component which take this object as input and display it's properties accordingly

Comment: Hmm. {{getRegion().name}} is displaying [object Object]. Any ideas?

Comment: use {getRegion() | json}} to check how it is coming and what to do to access it